# BitLocked drive not recognised as encrypted

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, encryption, bitlocker

So I was an idiot and was re-allocating space between an encrypted partition (that had been unlocked) and a standard partition on the same physical SSD. After the operation, everything looked right.

At my next reboot, I got a worrying screen stating that Windows was "Fixing" the two drives. I left it to do it's thing (figuring it would be worse again, if I interrupted the operation).

Now, the unencrypted drive (which had more space allocated to it) is working fine.

**The encrypted drive, however, isn't showing as encrypted** (no padlock). When I click on the drive, I can see the file system, and navigate fine. When I attempt to open a file, however, (say, a file called licence.txt) the contents are clearly encrypted.

Thus far I've tried:

- Rebooting
- Checking the BitLocker status (which is currently Off, and I don't think turning it on would be a good idea)
- Googling. A lot.
- Looking at the BitLocker Recovery Tool (and even if I could get the thing to install, I don't think it will do the job as it seems to be for recovering drives that register as BitLocker protected).

Any insight you could offer would be greatly appreciated. Even help with a relevant search term, at this stage!

Thanks in advance

**Edit 1:** It gets even worse. It looks like *most* of the files are encrypted; but not all of them. My guess is when the partitions were being shuffled about, some files were physically moved, and remained unencrypted; while the unmoved files were untouched on the disk.

**Edit 2:** I've just ordered another external SSD and will try using the BitLocker Recovery Tool on it. It should arrive tomorrow. In the meantime, if anyone has any insight; feel free to comment. Thanks again :-)

**Edit 3:** I've uploaded and shared some examples of the still encrypted file contents, versus what it should be:  https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1MwHWanP9BUY80ywNpTjW_FOKn03-Rbxd?usp=sharing

Comment: Exactly what do you mean by "the contents are clearly encrypted"?

Comment: Thanks, user1686. Say I open a text file on this drive (one that should just be simple, like licence.txt) using Notepad++; it will be filled with odd / unrecognisable characters, instead of the text for the MIT Licence (for example). 

Edit: I've uploaded and shared some examples. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1MwHWanP9BUY80ywNpTjW_FOKn03-Rbxd?usp=sharing

Comment: You re-partitioned a drive without first making a drive image?

Comment: "So I was an idiot" Yep, DrMoishe, I certainly did :-/